# Chapter 4 Stroustrup Drill. A challenging step (at least for me!)

Tags: c++

I'm working through Stroustrups's "Programming Principles and Practice using C++" and got stuck in one exercise.

Here are the indications :

```
1) Write a program that consists of a while-loop that (each time around the loop) reads in two ints and then prints them. Exit the program when a terminating '|' is entered.

2)Change the program to write out the smaller value is: followed by the smaller of the numbers and the larger value is: followed by the larger value.

3)Augment the program so that it writes the line the numbers are equal (only) if they are equal.

4)Change the program so that it uses doubles instead of ints.

5)Change the program so that it writes out the numbers are almost equal after writing out which is the larger and the smaller if the two numbers differ by less than 1.0/100.

6) Now change the body of the loop so that it reads just one double each time around. Define two variables to keep track of which is the smallest and which is the largest value you have seen so far. Each time through the loop write out the value entered. If it’s the smallest so far, write the smallest so far after the number. If it is the largest so far, write the largest so far after the number.
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
    int main(){

    double number1 = 0;
    double number2 = 0;
    double maximum = 0;
    double minimum = 0;


    cout << " Keep entering numbers. If you want to exit the program press alt + z" << endl;
    while (cin >> number1 && cin >> number2) {

if (number1 == '@' || number2 == '@')    {
    break;
    }

else if (number1 < number2){
    cout << "The smaller value is " << number1 << '.' << endl;
    cout << "The larger value is " << number2 << '.' << endl;
    maximum = number2;
    minimum = number1;
    if  (number2 - number1 < 0.01) {
        cout << "The numbers are almost equal";

    }
}

else if ( number1 > number2) {
    cout << "The smaller value is " << number2 << '.' << endl;
    cout << "The larger value is " << number1 << '.' << endl;
    maximum = number1;
    minimum = number2;
        if  (number1 - number2 < 0.01) {
        cout << "The numbers are almost equal";
    }

}

else {
    cout << "Both numbers are the same." << endl;
}
    }
```

Can somebody help me modify this to find the largest, smallest number? 
I've read about it and found a sorted vector solution but I can't seem to apply it to my problem.

Much appreciated :)

Comment: we don't do your homework for you.

Comment: This isn't homework. I'm out of college a long time ago! Learning on my own a new skill and looking for helop because I don't want to get stuck.

Comment: You say *"...found a sorted vector solution but I can't seem to apply it to my problem"* - so *show the attempt*, explain what it did and didn't do, what you expected, what you don't understand about "why", how you tried to investigate etc.....

Comment: You're not looking for help to learn, you're asking someone else to do it for you.   Ask specific questions if you're having specific problems.  Otherwise, go read a book.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep a running count of the maximum and minimum and not make structural changes to your existing program,

You'll need to '#include < algorithm >' unless you want to roll your own min and max functions.

Instead of:

```
maximum = number1;
minimum = number2;
```

Use this:

```
maximum = (maximum < max(number1, number2)) ? max(number1, number2) : maximum;
minimum = (minimum > min(number1, number2)) ? min(number1, number2) : minimum;
```

Comment: At this point of the book I have not seen those steps (the min max ones). Maybe a different method? (I'm guessing using vectors may work but I don't know how to st it all up).

Answer (score 0):

For Exercise 6, you don’t have to use std::vector. You can keep track the largest and smallest values in single variables called minn and maxn as shown in the following code snippet:

```
int
main()
{
    std::string quit("|");
    int i = 0;
    std::string s;
    double n;
    std::vector < double >v = { 0.0, 0.0 };

    double maxn = std::numeric_limits < double >::lowest();
    double minn = std::numeric_limits < double >::max();

    std::vector < double >in_meters;

    while (std::cin >> s) {
        if (quit.compare(s) == 0)
            break;

        if (reject(s))
            continue;

        n = str2meters(s);
        std::cout << n << " ";

        in_meters.push_back(n);

        if (maxn < n) {
            std::cout << "the largest so far" << std::endl;
            maxn = n;
        }

        if (minn > n) {
            std::cout << "the smallest so far" << std::endl;
            minn = n;
        }

        v[i] = n;
        if (i == 1) {
            std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
            prn(v);
        }

        i = (i + 1) % 2;
    }

    prng(in_meters);

    return 0;
}
```

I have used std::vector for Exercises 2 and 5:

```
void
prn(std::vector < double > &v)
{

    const double one_percent = 1.0 / 100.0;

    std::cout << "the smaller value is: " << v[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "the larger value is: " << v[1] << std::endl;

    if ((v[1] - v[0]) < one_percent)
        std::cout << "are almost equal" << std::endl;

}
```

and Exercises 9-11, too:

```
void
prng(std::vector < double > v)
{

    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());

    for (auto k : v)
        std::cout << k << " " ;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    double sum = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0);
    std::cout << "number of values " << v.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sum of values " << sum << std::endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making it complicated, start with this using 'std_lib_facilities'

```
    #include "..\..\std_lib_facilities.h"

    int main() {

        cout << "type in two integers or a '|' to terminate the program:\n";
        int x1 = 0;
        int x2 = 0;

        while (cin >> x1 >> x2)
        {
            cout << x1 << ", " << x2 << "\n";
        }

    keep_window_open("x");
    }
```

Comment: Not sure what `std_lib_facilities.h` brings to the table here, except for the `keep_window_open()` abomination.